# SPARQL query - filter by date

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I am using this patents site https://data.epo.org/linked-data/sparql.html. The goal is to obtain only the results of this year's patents. To do this, I'm filtering by filingDate. I am using this query:

```
prefix cpc: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/cpc/>
prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
prefix ipc: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/ipc/>
prefix mads: <http://www.loc.gov/standards/mads/rdf/v1.rdf>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix patent: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/patent/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix st3: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/st3/>
prefix text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>
prefix vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?application ?appNum ?filingDate ?authority {
  ?application rdf:type patent:Application ;
      patent:applicationNumber ?appNum ;
      patent:filingDate        ?filingDate ; 
      patent:applicationAuthority ?authority ;
      .
} 
WHERE {
  ex:filingDate ?filingDate .
  FILTER (xsd:date(?filingDate) >= xsd:date("2022-01-01"))
} LIMIT 10
```

However, instead of the results expected, I am getting an error.

```
Parse error: 
prefix cpc: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/cpc/>
prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
prefix ipc: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/ipc/>
prefix mads: <http://www.loc.gov/standards/mads/rdf/v1.rdf>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix patent: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/patent/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
prefix st3: <http://data.epo.org/linked-data/def/st3/>
prefix text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>
prefix vcard: <http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?application ?appNum ?filingDate ?authority {
  ?application rdf:type patent:Application ;
      patent:applicationNumber ?appNum ;
      patent:filingDate        ?filingDate ; 
      patent:applicationAuthority ?authority ;
      .
} 
WHERE {
  ex:filingDate ?filingDate .
  FILTER (xsd:date(?filingDate) >= xsd:date("2022-01-01"))
} LIMIT 10


Encountered " "where" "WHERE "" at line 22, column 1.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "limit" ...
    "offset" ...
    "order" ...
    "values" ...
    "group" ...
    "having" ...
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't know why you put some triple patterns before the `WHERE` part - that is obviously wrong, you have to put all inside the `WHERE` clause. And yes, you can omit the `WHERE` keyword, but then you cannot later on raise another `WHERE` - why did you do this? And what is `ex:filingDate` then?

Comment: `SELECT ?application ?appNum ?filingDate ?authority {   ?application rdf:type patent:Application ;       patent:applicationNumber ?appNum ;       patent:filingDate        ?filingDate ;        patent:applicationAuthority ?authority .   FILTER (?filingDate >= "2022-01-01"^^xsd:date) } LIMIT 10` - note, there query gets a timeout, either there is no new patent yet, or there are too many and the engine isn't efficient on literal filters. If you try for year 2021 it works instantly

Comment: That's it! Solved the problem.